# django rest framework serializer raising invalid errors

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, request

```
class AdvanceSearchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    all_of_these_words = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    this_exact_phase = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    any_of_these_words = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, required=False)


class myclass(viewsets.Viewsets):
    serializer = AdvanceSearchSerializer(data = request.data)
```

it works fine. for now im passing data from post request in postman as form-data but when I change it to raw and wih json format it raising the below errors. show that this field is required even though i have set it to null true.

```
  {
        "response": false,
        "return_code": "field_error",
        "result": [],
        "message": {
            "all_of_these_words": [
                "This field may not be blank."
            ],
            "this_exact_phase": [
                "This field may not be blank."
            ],
            "any_of_these_words": [
                "This field may not be blank."
           ]
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: check serializer.is_valid() and serializer.errros()

Comment: Send me your postman screen of raw

Comment: Problem is it works when i dont pass any values in key in form data but doesn't work in raw i have all the keys same as in form data. It makes me mandatory to add data while passing in raw form.